# How to cast date column in SQL Server 2008 R2 to have drill down effect in the Excel format

Tags: t-sql, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I'm very new on this blog and probably I am not expressing my self correctly, but what I want is: I have a stored procedure where I am grabbing data and inside there I have a date column. I am using that stored procedure to create a report using SSRS and when I am exporting the report to Excel format and applying filter on date column I'd like to have a drill down effect on filter which shows first year and when I toggle down it should show me the month and then the days.

So how should I convert the date column that I can have a drill down effect?

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), ORIGINAL_ORDER_DATE.THE_DATE, 103) AS ORIGINAL_ORDER_DATE
```

This is how i'm casting my date column inside the stored procedure.

This is how my date column look in Excel

[image]

This is how I'd like to have it

[image]

Comment: It might be a better idea to build that functionality in to your report, so that it needn't be exported to excel to get that functionality. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-an-expand-or-collapse-action-to-an-item-report-builder-and-ssrs

Comment: hmm actually the report is fine how it is right  now i don't want the drill down effect at report level i just want that effect only when i'm applying filter in excel format as you can look to the image which i've attached.